# How can I remove a user from an Organization?

Tags: organization, toit

I am able to add users (emails) to a given organization. However, I don't seem to find a way to *remove* a user from an organization.
Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's not a feature that is public available atm. But something we are working on.

If you have a user you want to have removed from your org, write to us at support@toit.io or via the chat on our webpage.

Sorry for the inconveniences.

Comment: Hi Jesper,  thanks for your reply. I may need this but in about 2 months..so if you agree we can leave the question open/unresolve until you implement this. In the meanwhile, I will contact support if I need to. Also, if you want me to open a feature request in toit github, let me know.